# Identify IOS in template

Tags: html, ios, templates, auth0, desktop

I am using auth0 server .

I am using auth0's email template for mail sending.

manage.auth - > branding -> email template

I am using IOS device as front end

using this email template(Verification email- using link) , send email towards the corresponding email id. Inside this a confirmation link is placed.

while open the mail from the IOS device, the confirmation mail is redirect towards the app.

my requirement is while open the mail from a desktop I want to redirect it into a webpage.

in this existing template , I didn't understand how can i check its desktop or its IOS, if its IOS , redirect to the existing redirect URL, if its not IOS and the redirect to a web page( currently google.com)

How can I do this.

I am attaching the existing html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      .ExternalClass,.ExternalClass div,.ExternalClass font,.ExternalClass p,.ExternalClass span,.ExternalClass td,img {line-height: 100%;}#outlook a {padding: 0;}.ExternalClass,.ReadMsgBody {width: 100%;}a,blockquote,body,li,p,table,td {-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;}table,td {mso-table-lspace: 0;mso-table-rspace: 0;}img {-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;border: 0;height: auto;outline: 0;text-decoration: none;}table {border-collapse: collapse !important;}#bodyCell,#bodyTable,body {height: 100% !important;margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: ProximaNova, sans-serif;}#bodyCell {padding: 20px;}#bodyTable {width: 600px;}@font-face {font-family: ProximaNova;src: url(https://cdn.auth0.com/fonts/proxima-nova/proximanova-regular-webfont-webfont.eot);src: url(https://cdn.auth0.com/fonts/proxima-nova/proximanova-regular-webfont-webfont.eot?#iefix)format("embedded-opentype"),url(https://cdn.auth0.com/fonts/proxima-nova/proximanova-regular-webfont-webfont.woff) format("woff");font-weight: 400;font-style: normal;}@font-face {font-family: ProximaNova;src: url(https://cdn.auth0.com/fonts/proxima-nova/proximanova-semibold-webfont-webfont.eot);src: url(https://cdn.auth0.com/fonts/proxima-nova/proximanova-semibold-webfont-webfont.eot?#iefix)format("embedded-opentype"),url(https://cdn.auth0.com/fonts/proxima-nova/proximanova-semibold-webfont-webfont.woff) format("woff");font-weight: 600;font-style: normal;}@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {#bodyTable,body {width: 100% !important;}a,blockquote,body,li,p,table,td {-webkit-text-size-adjust: none !important;}body {min-width: 100% !important;}#bodyTable {max-width: 600px !important;}#signIn {max-width: 280px !important;}}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <center>
      <table
        style='overflow-x: hidden; width: 600px;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: "ProximaNova", sans-serif;border-collapse: collapse !important;height: 100% !important;'
        align="center"
        border="0"
        cellpadding="0"
        cellspacing="0"
        height="100%"
        width="100%"
        id="bodyTable"
      >
        <tr>
          <td
            align="center"
            valign="top"
            id="bodyCell"
            style='-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;margin: 0;padding: 20px;font-family: "ProximaNova", sans-serif;height: 100% !important;'
          >
            <div class="main">
              <p
                style="text-align: center;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; margin-bottom: 30px;"
              >
                <img
                  src="https://cdn.auth0.com/styleguide/2.0.9/lib/logos/img/badge.png"
                  width="50"
                  alt="Your logo goes here"
                  style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;border: 0;height: auto;line-height: 100%;outline: none;text-decoration: none;"
                />
              </p>

              <h1>Welcome to {{ application.name}}!</h1>

              <p>Thank you for signing up. Please verify your email address by clicking the following link:</p>
              
              <p><a href="{{ url }}">Confirm my account</a></p>

              <p>
                If you are having any issues with your account, please don’t hesitate to contact us by replying to
                this mail.
              </p>

              <br />
              Thanks!
              <br />

              <strong>{{ application.name }}</strong>

              <br /><br />
              <hr style="border: 2px solid #EAEEF3; border-bottom: 0; margin: 20px 0;" />
              <p style="text-align: center;color: #A9B3BC;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                If you did not make this request, please contact us by replying to this mail.
              </p>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: template design]

**I need in the below line , if the device is IOS the link is URL(same as existing) and if the device is not IOD, it must be google.com**

```
<p><a href="{{ url }}">Confirm my account</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
{% if request.headers.user-agent == "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/69.0.3497.105 Mobile/15E148 Safari/605.1" %}
<p><a href="{{ url }}">Confirm my account</a></p>
{% elif request.headers.user-agent == "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; Pixel 2 XL Build/PPP3.180510.008) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Mobile Safari/537.36" %}
<p><a href="{{ diffrent-url }}">Confirm my account</a></p>
{% endif %}
```

you can user request header to indentify the user

https://github.com/WICG/ua-client-hints/blob/main/README.md

above link will you help you understand the different headers for different users.

Comment: I tried this , but after setting this I didn't getting mail. then I changes else if to else for checking , so I got mail, but then in mail , I am not getting the link, Confirm my account is just showing as a text not as link

Comment: this if clause not identifying IOS

Comment: yes i know this if statement is not identifying ios that's why i provided link. you have to find the header.user-agent value for IOS.

Comment: I tried a lot of ways , but nothing detecting  ..  I am using the auth 0 email template. in auth 0 its the actual checking method ?